# Show empty[no country/city] continental based map & on touch get cliked latitude,longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, google-maps-static-api

I'm developing an app in Android that shows an empty map [without country/city or any information]. How can I achieve that using MapView?

I found a solution using static map, but can I get touched latitude, longitude in that, as static map returns image?

Need to achieve following kind of : http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=512x512&center=london&zoom=6&style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off

But I need this to be in MapView so that I can get touched location & perform operation on that.

Any help or hint are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the [google maps sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro). In it you can easily see how it's done.

Don't forget to create a [API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) from a *debug* certificate fingerprint.

Comment: hi cerdo, thanks for reply i have checked this functions before but i couldnt find static map implementation. If its available plz can u share that part or source.